# CMD/Powershell - Copy folder structure with one level of folder omitted

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I have a folder structure like this:

```
Animals
    │
    ├───Land
    │   │
    │   ├───Dog
    │   │       DogBarking.jpeg
    │   │
    │   └───Tiger
    │           TigerRunning.jpeg
    │           TigerStanding.jpeg
    │
    └───Water
        │
        ├───Crocodile
        │       CrocodileAttacking.jpeg
        │       CrocodileSwimming.jpeg
        │
        └───Dolphin
                DolphinPlaying.jpeg
```

I want to copy Animals folder along with all sub-folders and files to a destination such that the first level of sub-folder (Land, Water) is omitted. The copied folder structure should be:

```
Animals
    │
    ├───Crocodile
    │       CrocodileAttacking.jpeg
    │       CrocodileSwimming.jpeg
    │
    ├───Dog
    │       DogBarking.jpeg
    │
    ├───Dolphin
    │       DolphinPlaying.jpeg
    │
    └───Tiger
            TigerRunning.jpeg
            TigerStanding.jpeg
```

Please let me know if this possible via CMD/powershell. Thanks in advance.

I tried xcopy and Robocopy commands, but was not able to achieve the desired results with any of them.

Comment: Please open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `for /?` and read the output help. Then run `robocopy /?` and read again the output help. There can be used __in a batch file__ `@for /D %%I in ("C:\Source Path\Animalst\*") do @%SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe "%%I" "C:\Destination Path\Animals" /S /NDL /NFL /NJH /NJS /R:1 /W:3 >nul` if the source folder `Animals` does not contain hidden folders ignored by `for /D` and the folders `Land` and `Water` do not contain itself files as they would be also copied all to destination folder `Animals`.

Comment: Replace both `%%I` by just `%I` if you want to run the command line directly in a command prompt window. I would recommend to remove in that case also both `@`, the __ROBOCOPY__ option `/NJS` and the redirection `>nul` to see what is going on during the execution of this command line, i.e. use `for /D %I in ("C:\Source Path\Animalst\*") do %SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe "%I" "C:\Destination Path\Animals" /S /NDL /NFL /NJH /R:1 /W:3` in the command prompt window.

Comment: Yes. It is possible: `GetChildItem -Directory Animals//*/* | ForEachObject {MoveItem $_ -Destination 'Animals/'}`

Answer (score 0):

Try following.  I used XCOPY because the PS Copy-Item was not copy files (only folders) :

```
$oldFolder = 'C:\temp\Animals'
$newFolder = 'C:\temp\Animals2'
$folders = get-childItem -Path $oldFolder -Directory -Recurse

$folders | foreach { $splitArray = $_.Fullname.Replace($oldFolder, '').Split('\'); $destination = [string]::Join('\',$splitArray[2..$splitArray.Count]); Write-Host $_.Fullname ($newFolder + '\' + $destination); XCOPY /I $_.Fullname ($newFolder + '\' + $destination)}
```